# I for insert frame is disabled or changed

Tags: shortcut

while opening the insert frame menu i accidentally pressed a button that made blender ask me to select a key which i left or right clicked to and now i can't use i to insert keyframes on my armature.
the "I" Key still works on everything else besides the objects i did this to.
any way to reverse this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after looking into it i found the I key was actually deleted in the insert keyframe menu likely because i clicked instead of gave it a key using the system preference.
[image]

Using space to search for and restore the shortcut key i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Try going to scene settings (icon with the light, cylinder and sphere) and make sure the "keying sets" tab is empty.

Comment: Its definitely empty